# Alternative characterizations of analytic functions

Tags: reference-request, analytic-functions

a function $f$ is analytic on an open set $ \Omega$ if for every compact $K \subset \subset \Omega $  there exist a constant $c>$ such that :

$$\sup_K|f^{(n)}(x)| \leq c^{n+1}n!, \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$$

can someone recommend a reference for the proof please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is immediate from Taylor's Theorem. One wonders why you want that "reference". If, say, you're writing a research paper you don't  need a reference, simply saying "Taylor's theorem shows that..." should be more than enough justification.

If otoh you want a reference with a solution to your homework you should work it out for yourself. Hint: Consider the Lagrange form of the remainder; if $|x-a|<1/c$ then $c^n(x-a)^n\to0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Thank you sir; Do you mean that the convergence of the Taylor's series is sufficient for the analycity ?

Comment: No of course not. For $f$ to be analytic the Taylor series of $f$ has to  converge to $f$. GIven thhose inequalities on the derivatives, this is immediate from  Taylor's theorem; otoh the fact that $|f^{(n)}|\le c^n n!$ implies that the Taylor series _converges_ has nothing to  do with Taylor's theorem.